# R Shiny Server - set a loading animation on application startup

Tags: r, docker, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I've used shinyapps.io in the past and it provides a loading animation (spinner) while the application starts up. This is useful because I load 200MB of `.RData`-files into the memory (once on startup, not for every `server()`). This takes up to 40 seconds (in future, I will transition towards storing the data in a database, but for now this is what I got).

For other applications, I've used the docker image `rocker/shiny` and wanted to fully transition to a Docker-based approach and put all my shiny applications on one server and move away from shinyapps.io. However, the one issue I have with this application is that it **does not display a loading animation while it starts** so the user is left with a grey screen for a good 30-40 seconds while the data is loaded in the background.

As for the code, I load all data and then I source `ui.R` and `server.R` before running `shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`.

Does any of you know a way to specify a loading animation on startup of the application (I haven't found anything in the server configuration itself but I could have overlooked something)? Or have you found a nice workaround to achieve the desired result?

Comment: The data are loaded in `server` ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent no, the data is loaded outside server and ui, before they are even sourced, so it is only loaded once and not once per user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was to follow this workaround suggested here: http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2018/01/01/show-progress-bar-when-pre-loading-data-in-shiny-app

The idea is that we initialize all data variables with `NULL`. Then there is a `readData()` function outside of `server` and `ui` where we load all the data into the global variables and at the beginning of the `server` function block we check if one of our data variables `is.null()` which would lead us to call the `readData()` function.

It is an okay solution for my problem as it's a nice workaround, yet I wasn't able to figure out how to actually display a loading animation on startup, just while loading the data. I hope this helps people with a similar same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious how to do this myself and could not find anything online other than this thread. After throttling my connection and a few breakpoints in inspect element it is all on the website end, not Shiny end.

On first page load they have their CSS animation which is followed by an Ajax request to the status page for the app `https://username.shinyapps.io/yourApp/__health-check__/`

Since this URL goes through a failed to load 10 second loop for 'Sleeping' apps, I presume the normal URL starts the application, not it. Once the application is loaded the health check URL will return a 200 response (with the below JSON). The loop for the Ajax request is then considered complete and it calls `reload()` which is a shortcut for `window.location.reload(true);`

```
{
  "Idle": 0,
  "Count": 1,
  "TypeCounts": {
    "http": 0,
    "sockJS": 0,
    "muxedSockJS": 0,
    "pending": 0,
    "preload": 1
  },
  "Age": 0.956551659,
  "Procs": 1
}
```

This satiated my curiosity of *how* so I have not (yet) looked further into how it actually runs or how it determines it is healthy and running but I perhaps someone else (or future me) will investigate this further for fun.